# Preventing additional code from running until AJAX request returns something

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the example below I made a function that strictly accepts parameters and makes an ajax call and then returns the result. The problem is that since the AJAX request is async the rest of my JavaScript which relies on the return value continues running. In the other function below called anotherFunction().

Are there any techniques to not run the remaining code in anotherFunction() until the expirDates are returned? I am aware that I can just put the ajax call directly in anotherFunction() then write the remainder of my code in the ajax success function, but I wanted to make the ajax request reusable..

```
function GetExpirationDates(end, start) {
    var data = {
        end: end,
        start: start
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetExpirationDates", "Products")',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            // Success logic goes here here
               return data;

        }
    });
}


function anotherFunction() {
    // code here...

    var expirDates = GetExpirationDates(end, start);

    // more code here that continues to run, but relies on expirDates...
}
```

Comment: Use a callback! You can't `return` from an async call

Comment: You can also pass a function as a parameter when you first call your `GetExpirationDates()`. That way you can call the referred function on success etc. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6014441/3279876

Comment: @tymeJV I know it doesn't make sense to return from an async call which is why I asked this question. So are you saying call another function inside of the ajax success function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `return` statement within `GetExpirationDates` using [`.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then) chained to `expirDates` to perform task when jQuery promise returned from `GetExpirationDates`

```
function GetExpirationDates(end, start) {
    var data = {
        end: end,
        start: start
    }
    // return jQuery promise object from `GetExpirationDates`
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetExpirationDates", "Products")',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}


function anotherFunction() {
    // code here...

    var expirDates = GetExpirationDates(end, start);

    // more code here that continues to run, but relies on expirDates...
    expirDates.then(function(data) {
      // do stuff with `data`
    }, function error(err) {
      // handle errors from `$.ajax()`
    })
}
```

Comment: should remove `success` , it's not doing anything and could be misleading, or at least the `return` does nothing

Comment: I am starting to come to the conclusion that there is really no work around for my question. What it comes down to is that I am going to have to split up my code all over the place since I am going to have a bunch of Ajax Success functions. I was more concerned about breaking up my code more than anything, but now that I know it is the only way, I am good! Another alternative is to make one huge functions and have ajax calls within ajax calls.

Comment: @BlakeRivell not sure why you say that. This approach using promises is most common approach to what you are trying to do and lets you streamline your code effectively

Comment: I agree, it answers my question perfectly and my code will be cleaner.

Comment: @guest271314 Great response which is definitely what I was looking for, but is programming like this considered bad practice before I go and implement it?

Comment: @BlakeRivell quite the contary. Important to realize that using promise chains allow for errors to be caught from anywhere in the chain and they will end up in the final catch

Comment: @guest271314 Hmm I am actually getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined error when the code gets to dates.then when I know for sure my Ajax call is returning something.

Comment: @BlakeRivell Can you fork jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9pde2rp7/ to demonstrate ?

Comment: @guest271314 I apologize, I didn't see that I am supposed to put return before $.ajax and remove the success.

Comment: @BlakeRivell No worries. Does `js` at post return expected results ?

Comment: No for some reason I am not getting results. But when I pop the ajax directly taking it out of its separate function and putting it into the main function it works fine. So I am not sure why it isn't loading the data.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103962/discussion-between-blake-rivell-and-guest271314).